# How to add new field to auth context than just the uid() in supabase?

Tags: authentication, authorization, supabase, supabase-database, supabase-js

Currently as I have found out that the Supabase only exposes ***auth.uid()*** to do query related to the logged in user. So I can create, read, update and delete based on the user who is logged in, what I wanna do is to store new field ***"organization"*** with the user(I know how to do this) and then later I want to be able to do crud based on it like ***auth.organization()***, is there any way to achieve query based on something like this ***auth.organization()***?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can encode it in the jwt and then access the JWT like so: https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/row-level-security#authjwt

```sql
create policy "User is in team" 
on my_table
to authenticated
using ( team_id in (select auth.jwt() -> 'app_metadata' -> 'teams'));
```